# Is it spam or does Stack Overflow have a really stressed/mean community that dislikes questions for fun?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, community

This is a serious question. I carefully wrote a question just so I don't get downvotes, and I still gather 3. Plus I even gave my fix since I fixed the bug on my own.

Comment: We're not stressed or mean -- we just don't allow any fun.

Comment: We have a [fun] tag.

Comment: [This should be a good read](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: All the new "hardcore" comers to the site have a huge control problem and just downvote / vote close anything they don't like, all the top answers on google are from SO yet most of these questions are closed now because of some know-it-all kiddies.

Comment: On Meta, a downvote means that the person disagrees.

Comment: well people disagree all the time in real life too, but would it be fair to make him lose respect in his community just because someone disagrees with him?

Comment: First thing to learn in a community like this. People are down voting a post, not a user.

Comment: the user has rep points that are connected with post downvotes.

Comment: That's just how it works *here*.  On other Meta sites, rep comes from the main site and is unaffected on Meta.

Comment: I imagine your question's being downvoted because it's just... unclear what you're asking about, and it's also an angry rant. But as for your troubles on Stack Overflow: voters can be pretty harsh there. Gotta tread carefully when asking questions there, and not get hung up on downvotes, because they're going to happen. Bear in mind this is an issue people are seriously concerned about and trying to work out what to do: [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/152515) has been around for a while and is _still_ alive.

Comment: Also consider that your StackOverflow questions don't show effort. You don't capitalize the start of sentences or use proper grammar, and don't show any effort or attempts besides saying "i've tried searching on google how to do it but nothing useful." Professionalism and effort matter a lot to this community.

Comment: Think of Stack Overflow like a steaming hot springs. You have to get in slowly toes first, then ankles and slowly adapt. But once you're immersed in it you see how awesome it really is.

Comment: I have no idea what the original question was, you can check my SO questions / answers, but I did notice all the new comer crybabies in the last few years.

Answer (score 22):

[image: Figure 1: Not helping]

Well, this probably doesn't help.